# Magento 1.4 productIdentifierType

Tags: c#, asp.net, magento, new-operator

i am having problems with retrieving my products, in 1.3 it worked and i just added some products on 1.4 but there is a new function in the capalogProductInfo called the product identifier, i don't know what to put in there, i tried passing down product type form list but i keep getting a error that says that the product does not exit.

can anyone help?

```
catalogProductInfo(sessionId, Product_id, CurrentStore, attributes, productIdentifierType)
```

Answer (score 3):

Before I defined the attributes I wanted back, I kept getting the same error (product does not exit):

```
catalogProductRequestAttributes attrib = new catalogProductRequestAttributes();
attrib.attributes = new string[] { "description", "name" };

catalogProductInfo(sessionId, Product_sku, CurrentStore, attrib, null)
```

Don't know about the productIdentifierType, but booth null and "sku" worked for me.

Comment: null used to work for me, but in Magento 1.5, if your SKUs are numeric, it now fails to find them. Passing in "sku" as the productIdentifierType doesn't seem to help either ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the [Magento API Catalog Product Info](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_product#catalog_product.info), that function requieres 3 arguments

- mixed product - product ID or Sku
- mixed storeView - store view ID or code (optional)
- array attributes - list of attributes that will be loaded (optional)

The 1.4 version seems to work the same way. Try to debug this class **Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api_V2**

```
/**
 * Retrieve product info
 *
 * @param int|string $productId
 * @param string|int $store
 * @param stdClass $attributes
 * @return array
 */
public function info($productId, $store = null, $attributes = null, $identifierType = null){}
```

Comment: oh i used the null and it works lol, my bad, but if it has a null value, y bother putting in a argument, what is it s purpose?

Comment: you have to use it otherwise the function will not receive the number parameters that are expected. Check example 5 from the documentation to understand better why the params should be there. http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Comment: The C# version of the API has four parameters as listed in the original question. The purpose of the 4th 'productIdentifierType' parameter is to tell Magento whether you are using SKU or product_id identifiers, I think.